# PerformSegue does not perform correctly

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

As you can see I'm trying to `performSegue` from Photo Action View Controller to Setting View Controller (`UITableViewController`).

[image]

So I'm performing from `PhotoActionViewController` directly (not using buttons etc.) because I want to perform this segue when user taps on one option from showing `AlertView`. Everything works like charm untill I set Class for the `SettingsViewController`. The segue performs but I can't see any `UITableViewCell`. How can I get this wor form me?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)imageViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"New Photo" message:@"Decide what you would like to do with this photo"];

    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Create New Project" block:^{
        // Pushing to New Project Settings Controller
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NPSSegue" sender:self];
    }];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add To Existing Project" block:^{
        NSLog(@"Add to existing");
    }];

    [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

I'm not posting `prepareForSegue` as it is empty for this moment and I don't know if anything should be there.

Comment: First off. Don't pass `self` into `performSegueWithIdentifier` just pass `nil`. Now looking at the rest...

Comment: Can you show the code for the `SettingsViewController`.

Comment: There is nothing in it! Just new class inheriting from `UITableViewController` so tehe are things like: `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` etc.

Comment: Remove all the `UITableViewController ` boilerplate code from `SettingsViewController`

Comment: Will check on that tomorrow because someone has taken my test iPhone

Answer (score 2):

whenever using segue programmatically we need to connect segue through one scene to another scene(viewcontroller) so create a button make it invisible and connect it to the destination scene and in uialertview delegate make button setEnabled:true and before pls set the segue Idetifier thanks and sorry for poor english.......

Comment: Thank you and I'm sure that this solution would work but what I wanted was to avoid creating invisible button. Removing all boilerplate code from `UITableViewController` worked for me like a charm!